# How URL redirect can be done without changing URL?

Tags: configuration, redirect

*I am asking to verify what I hear from my provider.*

I just bought domain name (let's say `foobar.com`) and I would like to redirect it to `helloworld.blog.com` in such way, that if somebody enters `foobar.com` in browser, the content from `helloworld.blog.com` is shown but the address is not changed  (`foobar.com` should remain).

*When user would like to go to sub-pages address will change, because entire site (WordPress) uses hardcoded absolute URLs. Pity, but that's OK.*

Previously I bought a domain at different provider, and I simply made 2 clicks to achieve this. Now I have different provider and he explains that even if such option is done by just clicking in reality there is small page created at original address (`foobar.com`) with frame pointing out to target site (`helloworld.blog.com`).

Is this true? I mean does redirecting URL (with URL kept) is done this way? I don't want to be accussed of traffic abuse or something like this (and besides it smells bad for me).

Or panel control at my current provider is too weak and missing crucial features?

*Note: I don't have problems in technical terms of writing such proxy html page with frame with it, I am simply looking for a way to ensure/deny it is done this way for real.*

Comment: Maybe the DNS stuff? If your domain `foobar.com` points to `helloworld.blog.com`'s IP? (Correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: @JeromeJ: DNS level redirection often doesn't work because the target HTTP server has to be configured to answer requests for the original domain name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is, in general, not true. What you can do is to configure a web server as a [reverse proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy), which will display a web site from a remote server like it was coming from the proxy server, without the need for some framing tricks.

However, it might be possible and even likely that your provider doesn't offer this functionality and he refers to the method you mentioned.